# How can I set gdm login screen time to 24 hour format?

Tags: centos, gdm, clock

I installed CentOS 6.4 within VMWare 7 by easy setup. Afterwards I had to change locale settings to German. Everythings works fine accept that the clock on the login screen is still in 12-hours-AM/PM-format. I want to change it to the 24-hour-format.

GDM Version is 2.30.4.

I tried the suggestions from the answers to [a similiar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17304/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-formatting-of-the-date-time-in-the-gnome-3-login-sc) and [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8268/how-do-i-configure-the-gnome-gdm-login-screen). However, the suggested command `gconf-editor` seems not to provide a way to configure the clock format at the login screen.

The other command `gsettings` is not available in my environment. How can I obtain it?

There are other suggestions involving `gdm.conf` but the only `gdm.conf` in my environment is a XML file and not located in the directories specified in these suggestions.

At [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/384713) there seems to be a support article about this issue, however bp;dr.

How can I set the login screen time to the 24 hour format?

Comment: `gsettings` is part of the package `glib2`.

Comment: @slm Thanks! `glib2` is already installed and there is no `gsettings` in the file system. In `gnome-control-center` I did not found an appropriate option.

Answer (score 2):

#### GNOME 2

Don't know exactly how to do this but here are some things to investigate.

1. gdm cache dir.
   I don't know how to change it but I found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale. Looks like there is a file dmrc which some settings related to GDM.

   #### for example

   My file is located here for user "saml", `/var/cache/gdm/saml/dmrc`.

   ```
   [Desktop]
   Language=en_US.utf8
   Layout=us
   ```
2. gnome-control-center

   There are several configurations accessible through the control panel (`gnome-control-center`) for GNOME which may allow you to change this setting.
3. Official docs

   The [official documentation for GDM is located here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/) for the various versions. Looking through it I didn't see a method to change the time format however.

#### GNOME 3

```
$ sudo -u gdm dbus-launch dconf write \
                 /org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-format "\"12h\""
```

Change the format to '24h' for 24 hour format.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigations! (1) in `/var/cache/gdm/[user]` are no files or dirs, (2) did not found anything approproated in the control center, (3) did not try. With your Gnome3 hint I tried to add `clock-format` but got errors. However, I tried to add the key "clock-format" manually with the gconf-editor. It doesn't work but probably because the key has not been bound to a schema. Searching on the net `gsettings` seems to do the job right but I failed to find a installable package. Finally I ended up installing CentOS manually with the right locale. Let you know, if it works.