# How to change the Gnome panel time format?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, clock

Gnome panel displays the time with 24hrs format but I want to change it to am/pm.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to *System Settings* (from the aggregate menu) and select *Date & Time*. Use the drop down menu on *Time Format* to select *AM/PM*:

[image]

or fire up `dconf-editor`, go to `org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-format` and turn off `Use default value` then set `Custom value` to `12h`:

[image]

Via terminal, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format 12h
```

---

Further customization of the date/time format can be done via `gnome-shell` extensions, see [Daniel's answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/348059/22142).

Comment: Thanks. That's so stupid that one has to go command line (and remember the command) to do that.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko - with more recent releases (not sure since when though...) you can do it via System Settings, see my updated post.

Comment: @don_crissti - yes, you are right. I was looking for another setting, how to show date with time. That is not available through System Settings, only through command line.

Answer (score 2):

November 2018, I was about to use your still-an-answer commandline method, dconf-editor, because Date and Time are not in Settings System now. I looked around a little more, and found Date and Time in Details. "Details" is burying the Date and Time format deuce in the details, IMHO. I had given up, until you threw me the bait that got me moving and looking for the setting again.

I checked out dconf-editor. It wasn't here. `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` then: org, gnome, desktop, interface, clock format: click on "12 hour" or "24 hour", pick from drop down list of two choices, 12 hour and 24 hour.

dconf-editor did add something. It notified that the re-read for menus in system still needed to be made, though I had made a change before that in Settings.Details.DateAndTime.

Comment: YES!, thank you. I was going to start mentioning about Gnome being in version 3.123123123 and still having stuff like this around.